# What's the functional purpose of this error stat and how is it enumerated/troubleshot?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, isp

[image]

The ISP is Charter Spectrum, and this is from their OEM(? or is it PL?) router.

Comment: Ask your ISP....

Comment: @DavidPostill Have you *ever* actually gotten a hold of anyone beyond tier-1 support?  Because in all the years that I've been using this ISP, I've never once had a gainful conversation with their "technical support" department.

Comment: They should at least have access to the manual for your router ...

Comment: I have the manual, it's [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UaG7HoK4bUnlMGs970F0DEhkYfEWdLxX/view?usp=drivesdk) but didn't see any mention of it